# I am trying to put 2 figures side by side using minipage and it mostly work, except the caption

Tags: captions, minipage, subcaption

I am trying to put 2 figures side by side using minipage and it mostly work, except the caption will always be to the left and doesn't center with the image. I tried moving the /centering around but it doesn't change anything. I am fairly new to the minipage setup. Am I missing something?

Here is the code as an example

```
\documentclass[utf8]{FrontiersinHarvard}
\usepackage{url,lineno,microtype,subcaption}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{subfigure}%
\setcounter{figure}{3}
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
\centering
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}%
        \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{logo2.eps}%
        \centering%
        \caption{}%
        \label{}
    \end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}%
        \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{logo1.eps}
        \centering%
        \caption{}%
        \label{}
    \end{minipage}%
\setcounter{subfigure}{-1}
    \caption{caption }
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Try with the `floatrow` package and its `subfloatrow` environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete, small but compilable document. Why you like to have in `subfigure` a `minipage` with `subcaption`?

Comment: @Teepeemm edited the code

Comment: the caption layout is due to code you have not shown, so it is hard to tell you what to change. Please always show a complete small document that shows the problem (you can use `example-image` as the image as it is available for such tests.

Comment: Edited again. My apologies

Comment: I can't get it to compile without error.  Can you?  (Don't ignore errors.)  Are you using the documentation for subcaption?  Why are you trying to load packages multiple times?

Comment: @Teepeemm Hi, after some changes yes can compile with no errors. A few warnings (mostly from references). the most common error was solved by changing 'subcaption' to 'caption' in the code

Answer (score 1):

I replaced `FrontiersinHarvard` with `article` (because loading it is too much work).

A subfigure is basically a minipage with captions (`\def\@captype{subfigure}` will achieve the same effect).

Note that the first paragraph after `\section` is not indented (deliberatedly).  You may need `\noindent` after the float.

Also, `\caption` begins and ends with `\par` so extra spaces before and after are ignored.

```
\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{url,lineno,microtype}% not used here
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}% Oh Boy!  A typewriter!
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}% remove error messages for missing files
\usepackage{float}% not used here (thankfully)
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

Some text here.

\begin{figure}[htp]%
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}%
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{logo2.eps}%
        \caption{}%
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{logo1.eps}
        \caption{}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{caption }
    \label{}
\end{figure}

Some text here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: So maybe it is something to do with document class? Because the rest of the code is now similar to this bar the document class. Unless i am missing something

Comment: @AdityaRivonkar I don't understand your comment.  You have `\begin{subfigure}...\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}`.  This has `\begin{figure}\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}` and no minipage.  They're not similar at all.